# Allowing legacy quiz answers to be viewed VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have been working on a fix for an issue for the last couple days and haven't gotten anywhere with it. What I am doing is updating a questionnaire. This questionnaire has some answers in drop down, some in radiobutton and some in checkbox. This questionnaire is created  created by loading the questions (one table in the database), answers (another table in the database) and the user responses are stored in another table. These are loaded by a select case function. So when I update the default answers in the database and try to view questionnaires with the old answers, I get an error stating the object was not set to an instance. So my question is, how do I allow more than one option to be readable in a select case, but have the same value for radiobuttons, or checkboxes.

Example:

How has the performance of your apprentice been:

X Good
X Bad

(needs to be viewable) 
And new answers:

How has the performance of your apprentice been:

X Good
X Could Be Improved

Any insight would be appreciated. The language is VB and the database is SQL

Comment: Your question is unclear. It would help if you can show the code you are using and explain how it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Version the answers?

Comment: Are the old answers (not responses) kept in the DB? We really need to see more on how you are retrieving the responses. Lets see some code, VB and SQL. Do you have any record of the questions associated with the quiz at the time it was taken? E.g if Answer A,  Answer B and Answer C were available when the quiz was taken and the response was A, what would you to expect to see if now Answer A, Answer C and Answer D are now the available answers?

Comment: As @Shawn suggests, instead of editing the existing answers, add new ones with a different version number. You can then only load the latest version answers when someone is answering questions but you can store a version number with each answer so you know what version answers they relate to.